# dynamically changing class

Tags: jquery

I have a lot of items of same class `“first”`

- I want to keep the class of the first item as such without change
- I want to make the class of the last item to “last”
- I  want to  remove class of the  all items  between first and last.

I have tried:

```
var mailHeadding = $('.first');
$.each(mailHeadding, function (indx) {
    if (indx == mailHeadding.length) {
        mailHeadding[indx].removeClass('first').addClass('last');
    }
    else if (indx != 0) {
        mailHeadding[indx].removeClass('first');
    }
});
```

Also `mailHeadding[indx]` replaced by `"this"`

Still this won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.first').slice(1)
    .removeClass('first')
    .last().addClass('last');
```

To explain what's going on here:

1. Select all members of the `first` class
2. Use the [`slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method to choose all but the first element in the selection
3. Use the [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) method to remove the `first` class from these elements.
4. Use the [`last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/) method to select only the final element in the selection
5. Use the [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) method to add the `last` class to this element.

Comment: +1 This has a definite advantage in browsers that support `querySelectorAll`. For some reason I assumed the `:gt()` selector is supported, but apparently not, which means Sizzle takes over.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.first:gt(0)').removeClass('first').last().addClass('last');
```

This uses [the greater than selector](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) to get all elements with the `.first` class greater than the zero-based index provided (in this case `0`, meaning the first).

Then it [uses `.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) to remove the `first` class from them, and [uses `.last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/) to jump to the last one and [uses `.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) to add the `last` class.

Comment: @Aaron - Oops, you're right. Fixed. Thanks for the heads up! :o)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (indx == mailHeadding.length)
```

This is your problem. The index is between `0` and `length - 1` (inclusive). So if the length is `5`, the indizes are `0, 1, 2, 3, 4`. So your comparison never results in `true`. You have to compare with `length - 1` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.<classes>:first-child').addClass('first');
$('.<classes>:not(:first-child)').removeClass('first');
$('.<classes>:last-child').addClass('last');
```

that sums up how you can use jquery to solve this problem

Comment: The elements already have the class `first`; He may not have another obvious class to substitute for `.classes`.

Comment: Remember that using `first-child/last-child` makes the assumption that they are all siblings, which may not be the case here. :o)